# how to set access in php to view page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

how to set access in php to view full page
suppose if you are admin so you have a permission to open any page and view it and if you are not admin user then it is showing error you are not admin but users have allow access to some limited page

enter code herehow can i do this

please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

see screen short example 
admin panel
[admin panel http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380834608.jpg](http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380834608.jpg)

user panel

[user panel http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380804093.jpg](http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380804093.jpg)

this is mysql tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `mem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mem_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is index.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();    
    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>
<form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
         <?php
            if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
            echo '<ul class="err">';
            foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
                echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
                }
            echo '</ul>';
            unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
            }
        ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116"><div align="right">Username</div></td>
    <td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
    <td><input name="password" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

connection.php file

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "simple_login";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

this is login_exec.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

this is auth.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

and this is home.php file

```
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center" class="style1">Login successfully </p>
<p align="center">This page is the home, you can put some stuff here......</p>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php">logout</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have quite a lot in your question body. What is the specific issue you’re facing?

Comment: i want to lock user account in some pages

Comment: That’s quite a big task, and doesn’t really fall into the realm of Q&A, which Stack Overflow is for. I suggest you read tutorials of authenticating in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of admin user. And check if member is admin  then ahow this, if not show this.

Comment: ok i created table of admin and then what can i do i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't use Prepared Statements with either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) your table is bound to be hacked. With Prepared Statements this can be avoided. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) out.

Anyway, your problem as described can be solved by creating a separate table containing administrators' id and then in the login system first get the user's row, get the id from that, and then check if that id exists in the administrator-table.

Comment: so how can do this in my code i already create a table of admin

Comment: yes can u give me a code and tell me how to do change my code

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do in this case would be to add a new row on your user database called user_ role or similar. As you only have two levels (admin/non-admin) set as a tinyint with a default of 0.

0 now indicates the user is just a user, but you can set their role to 1 indicating they are an admin.

Then all you do is check the users current role on any pages you want. I would suggest saving it into the $_SESSION so you don't have to query the DB on every page.

```
<?php if ( isset($_SESSION['user_role']) && $_SESSION['user_role'] == 1) : ?>
    admin panel html
<?php else : ?>
    redirect to login or display user panel html
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is a super simple role-based controller. Google RBAC to learn more about the more complicated concepts you can use later as your programs grow in size and complexity.

Comment: can i put like this in auth.php page <?php
 //Start session
 session_start();
 //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
      if ( isset($_SESSION['user_role']) && $_SESSION['user_role'] == 1) : 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
  header("location: index.php");
  exit();
 }
?>

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to change whole logic of your script but advised to Make an another table of admin you can  set another session variable admin into your login script as:

```
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            $_SESSION['Admin'] = "Admin";
```

now this session variable will present where you have session and for the restrict page you can bind content as from user..

```
<?php
session_start();
$value=$_SESSION['Admin'];
if(!empty($value))
{

//your website content
}
?>
```

lets for example if you want to hide a simple form by user then you can do this as:
page name is: form.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $value=$_SESSION['Admin'];
    if(!empty($value))
    { ?>
<form>
--- 
---- 
----
---
</form>
<?php }
else { ?>
<h1> You dont have permission to see this!</h1>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: i create a table of admin then where i put this $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            $_SESSION['Admin'] = "Admin"; code?

Comment: for registration ...do you have seperate table for user and admin?

Comment: ok, now in login script for admin add my code where i made an another session variable name "Admin.

Comment: please can u update a code in to my code becz i dont understand where i put ur code

Comment: just add another line $_SESSION['Admin'] = "Admin";   just get attention little bit on my code and instantly you will understand where to put this code

Comment: i add $_SESSION['Admin'] = "Admin"; line then where i put this code <?php
session_start();
$value=$_SESSION['Admin'];
if(!empty($value))
{

//your website content
}
?>